# Multi-level regression model: assumptions and their violations

Tags: regression, multilevel-analysis, assumptions

Some context:
I'm trying hypothesis testing using HLM/Multi-level regression modeling for the first time and ran into some problems testing the assumptions on my specified models.
All in all I specified two models (using Maximum Likelihood and setting the maximum iterations to 1000000 because the models wouldn't converge otherwise). In the fist model I'm testing whether there's a cross-level interaction and in the second model I'm only testing for the effects of Level 1 and Level 2 predictors.
My sample consists of 4 conditions nested within 35 people (repeated measures). To account for that, I specified AR1 (autoregressive first order) as covariance matrix (also because it offered the best fit indices). For the analyses I'm using the nlme R package.

Following Hox et al. (2017), I used the random coefficients model (containing level 1 predictors and slopes and level 2 predictors) for assumption testing.
Also following Hox et al. (2017), I tested the following assumptions:

- (multivariate) normal distribution of residuals (level 1 and level 2)
- independence of residuals (within and across levels)
- linearity
- multicollinearity
- (sufficiency of sample size)

Here are my results:

- in both models the assumption of independence of level 2 residuals is violated (intercept graphically shows high correlation with several slopes), level 2 residuals also seem to correlate with level 1 residuals
- in both models linearity between the predictors and the outcome variable ist violated
- in both  models normality is violated for level 2 residuals (intercept and slope)
- in one model normality of level 1 residuals in violated

I did some research on the topic and found that the lack of level 1 residuals' normality probably won't affect my analyses, but the violation of level 2 residuals' normality likely will distort standard errors. This could usually be adjusted by estimating robust standard errors, but my sample size seems to be too small for that. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any resources on the impact of the other assumptions' violations and what to do about them.

So my question is:
How will these violated assumptions affect my results (for example through distorted standard errors, ...) and are there ways to account for these violations?

Any input on the matter would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.